# Cannot connect to virtual machine with RDP

Tags: windows, azure, rdp, windows-10

I have set up 3 virtual machines running win10.
Previously everything has been working fine. However, now sometimes I cannot connect to the virtual machines with RDP.
The strange thing is that the server software (Traccar) and its webinterface is responding fine.
Any idea?

As I said this was all working fine a couple of months ago, win firewall and Azure ports are configured accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On each of the VM's verify that the following registry key is set to zero:

`HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server   Set "fDenyTSConnections" = 0`

If it is set to zero, then check the firewall and make sure the "Remote Desktop" rule is enabled.

If you are a fan of powershell then these two commands will set the registry variable to zero and enable the firewall rule for Remote access:

`Invoke-Command -Computername <computer name> -ScriptBlock {Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" –Value 0 }`

`Invoke-Command -Computername <computer name> -ScriptBlock {Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"}`

...Simply replace `<computer name>` with the name of the VM.

With these two conditions set the VM will be ready to accept remote connections. If you are still unable to reach them then I would look outside the VM. For example, do the VM's connect to the network via a "virtual switch" ? Is it possible someone messed with that?